# Are rest api URL and authentication parameters of a dataset secured?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have created a dataset with Power BI Desktop which gets data from a webservice. The dataset contains a private token in the URL. Then I have exported this dataset as a .pbix file and imported it into Power BI Service.
I want to share the dataset with other user. Will the other user see the dataset URL (which contains the private token) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two things in here Daniel.
One is about granting a role to your user who wants to see the report and it is completely up to you to control that. You can control the access so that it is read only and only to the visualisation layer and not to the data set. Means the connection details will always be secured and the call from report/dashboard to the API will not be visible to the users.

The second part is about encryption in transit. The PBI service url is encrypted with SSL and TLS for data security. It should not be the case that your credentials are exposed in clear text.

for details refer to following two blogs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/whitepaper-powerbi-security

https://blog.pragmaticworks.com/power-bi-and-data-security-compliance-and-encryption

the second blog link may be of interest to you as it highlights the datasource level encryption